# glDrawArray artifacts

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to render a grid of texture using glDrawArray and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, but there are artifacts when drawing, but distributed unevenly across the screen.

[Screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAs5l.png)

This is the code I use :

```
void draw() {
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.name);

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(cell_size, cell_size, 1);

    GLfloat vertices[w*8];

    { // populate only once and translate
        int i = 0;
        for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
            vertices[i++] = x; vertices[i++] = 0;
            vertices[i++] = x; vertices[i++] = 1;
            vertices[i++] = x+1; vertices[i++] = 0;
            vertices[i++] = x+1; vertices[i++] = 1;
        }
    }

    GLfloat texCoords[w*8];     
    const float off = 1.00f/16.0f;

    for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
            const int v = tiles[x+y*w];
            const float boff = v*off;
            texCoords[i++] = boff; texCoords[i++] = 0;
            texCoords[i++] = boff; texCoords[i++] = 1;
            texCoords[i++] = boff+off; texCoords[i++] = 0;
            texCoords[i++] = boff+off; texCoords[i++] = 1;
        }

        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, w*4);

        glTranslatef(0, 1, 0);
    }
    glPopMatrix();

}
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Where do you set up your projection and modelview matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on OGL, but you should change the texture render parameters, like this:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Yep, it was a texture problem. I changed it to GL_NEAREST and GL_NEAREST.

Answer (score 0):

`GL_NEAREST` filtering may work, but you may also want to consider changing your texture's edge wrapping (or even border) properties:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```